# MSMQ connection is not established

Tags: tcp, msmq

Application is using MSMQ services.
But some remote workstations cannot have MSMQ TCP connection established properly with server.
execute netstat -ano|findstr (msmq port), there is not TCP connection either in SYN-SENT or ESTABLISHED state from server to remote workstations.

But after restart MSMQ services in server and remote workstation, then TCP connection can be found and established.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the remote workstations are available for some time before becoming unavailable (network outage, maybe). MSMQ uses a retry mechanism to re-establish contact with the remote workstations. While the destination is unavailable and connection attempts continue to fail, the retry mechanism waits for longer and longer periods before new attempts are made. After the destination becomes available again, MSMQ won't know until a connection is attempted when the next retry interval is reached. Restarting MSMQ services resets the retry interval to zero and connections are immediately established.

Comment: Thank you.Is it possible to find out what the retry internal is?

Comment: Have a look at bottom of https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/02/08/msmq-and-session-acks-whats-the-story/ ((The URLs are broken (it's been 10 years!) but you can search for the registry values.)) SeqResend10Time is 6 hours, for example.